# Android: TabHost Activity acting weird after kill / OnSaveInstanceState not called

Tags: java, android, android-activity, tabactivity, activity-lifecycle

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, but as I just stumbled upon a [similar bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6225), it might be another bug as well. I was wondering if you could confirm this or even know a solution?

Okay, so I have a Tab Host containing two Activities A and B.

A is the "first" tab. So if I do the following:

- (A is opened)
- switch B
- close app
- kill the process
- open app again
- (B shows up)

then I everything is fine. Using Log I see that "onRestoreInstanceState" was called both for A and B.

Now, I do the following:

- (B is opened, I have NOT switched back to A)
- switch B
- close app
- kill the process
- open app again
- (B shows up)

then "onRestoreInstanceState" is called for B, but not for A. A get's a null Bundle in "onCreate".

If I switch to A, then back to B, it's fine again. After that, I can repeat the above behavior.

I know this sounds a bit confusing, but has anybody encountered this before?

Kind regards,
jellyfish

**Edit:**

I've repeated this for the other tab (keep A open, kill the activity, restore it, kill it again, restore it again). Then, B's "onCreate" is not called until I deliberately switch the tab; and no matter if it was restored before or not, it always gets the SavedInstance Bundle. So everything is fine.

**Edit2:**

As excepted, the same is true for rotation changes. Has seriously nobody noticed this before? Got this working both on 2.2 emulator and 2.3 phone.